# getting source code of a function

Tags: r, function, methods

I'm trying to see the source of the `analyzeSentiment()`function for the `SentimentAnalysis`package.
First I use `:::`:

```
> SentimentAnalysis:::analyzeSentiment
function (x, language = "english", aggregate = NULL, rules = 
defaultSentimentRules(), 
    removeStopwords = TRUE, stemming = TRUE, ...) 
{
    UseMethod("analyzeSentiment", x)
}
```

Using `methods()` I see that the function behaves according to the class of the input

```
> methods(analyzeSentiment)
[1] analyzeSentiment.character*          analyzeSentiment.Corpus*            
[3] analyzeSentiment.data.frame*        analyzeSentiment.DocumentTermMatrix*
[5] analyzeSentiment.TermDocumentMatrix*
```

When I try to look into these functions using `:::` they all rely on a function called `analyzeSentiment`.

```
> SentimentAnalysis:::analyzeSentiment.TermDocumentMatrix
function (x, language = "english", aggregate = NULL, rules = 
defaultSentimentRules(), 
    removeStopwords = TRUE, stemming = TRUE, ...) 
{
    analyzeSentiment(t(x), language, aggregate, rules, removeStopwords, 
        stemming, ...)
}
```

This is the very function I started out by looking into and which got me here. I'm curious as to how it's written. Please help me out of this vicious circle!

Comment: Try `getAnywhere(function_you_want)`

Comment: Have a look in [github](https://github.com/cran/SentimentAnalysis/blob/master/R/analyzeSentiment.R)

Comment: Tried `getAnywhere` but it's equivalent to `:::`. Ah thanks for the github tip!

Comment: Notice that function calls `analyzeSentiment(t(x),...)` and the transpose of a TermDocumentMatrix is a DocumentTermMatrix so the code is in `SentimentAnalysis:::analyzeSentiment.DocumentTermMatrix` which does not call `analyzeSentiment` again. So they didn't **all** rely on that function.